# Does Ashley ever apologize or can I tell her I don't trust her?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I hated how Ashley distrusted Shepard (despite me blowing up the collector base), but after she got injured I forgave her (she just almost died, I felt bad). But then she pulls out a gun on me! I was very disappointed that I couldn't voice this when she wanted to comeback to the Normandy, it just seemed that both answers (whether to allow her back or not) were more of because of her talents; I couldn't say "You're great but I can't trust you to take my orders so go to Hacket."

So I guess my question is: Is there ever a time in the game where she apologizes for pulling a gun on me, or ever a time where I can tell her I can't trust her anymore? (I know it's a game but part of the reason I love BioWare games is because it addresses these real world concerns, or at least it usually does.)

Comment: Don't know about Ashley, but Kaiden continues being a dick AFTER you don't shoot him. If I wasn't pure Paragon...

Comment: i shot ashley, she is infuriating in this game.

Answer (score 1):

When asking to get back together with Shepard she mentions the gunwaving as one of the things to get past, but never truly apologises. She states wishes that she had gone with Shepard in the second game in various mission commentary, however that's the extent of it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm really mad bioware didn't think to include some dialouge about that, made me wish I shot her, all the way up until I was invited to her room, I don't want to ruin it for anyone, but it is hilarious

Answer (score -1):

Well, I actually weren't so mad, when she pulled a gun at me. She's a Spectre, and she should protect the priority people, the Councils. Plus, imagine that your friend was healed by someone you count humanity's worst enemy, and than he began to accomplish missions for them. How would you react? Will you trust him so much?

And the answer is no, you can't say her she was an arsehole, but you can really not to take her on Normandy, and that will show you don't trust her =)

Comment: first of all i think i should get some credit for saving the universe from sovereign, but even if you dont count that, at that point in the game humanities worst enemy was the collectors, and i destroyed them, and after destroying them i turned myself in to the alliance, and after that i killed cerburus agents that were getting in the way of my alliance mission, so to say that she has nothing to apologize for is wrong, and im not saying she has to apologize, not everyone who is wrong apologizes, but id at least like the option to tell her that i cant trust her anymore if she doesnt apologize